# Что означает запрос на разрешения (permissions) начиная с 23 API в runtime?

Tags: android, android-permissions

Что означает запрос на  разрешения (permissions) начиная с `23 API` в `runtime`?

Разве недостаточно просто прописать нужные разрешения в Манифесте?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Системные разрешения делятся на две категории.

- [Нормальные](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/normal-permissions.html) - те что не несут прямой угрозы конфиденциальности Пользователя. Система утвердит разрешения автоматически.
- [Небезопасные](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous) - те что несут угрозу конфиденциальности Пользователя. Для таких разрешений Система запросит явного одобрения Пользователя на их использование.

  В любой версии `Android` разрешения из этих двух категорий все равно необходимо декларировать в Манифесте. "Эффект" декларирования проявляется в зависимости от версии `Android` и уровня `target SDK` для приложения.
- `Android 5.1` (и ниже) и `target SDK - 22` (и ниже) - Пользователи могут утверждать разрешения (permissions) для приложений  только когда это приложение устанавливается/обновляется
- `Android 6.0` (и выше) и `target SDK - 23` (и ниже и выше) - Пользователи могут утверждать/отменять разрешения (permissions) для приложений и после их установки. В процессе работы с ними (`runtime`).

Если вашему приложению требуется "небезопасное" разрешение, вы должны проверить, имеете ли вы это разрешение каждый раз, когда выполняете операцию, требующую это разрешение.

Некоторые методы:

- [ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)) - метод проверяет , имеете ли вы (приложение) разрешение. Возвращает `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED` если есть, приложение может перейти к требуемой операции. Возвращает `PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED` если нет, приложение должно явно запросить разрешение.
- [shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String)) - метод позволяет определить необходимость объяснения Пользователю необходимости запрашиваемого разрешения. Возвращает `true` если приложение запрашивало это разрешение ранее, и пользователь отклонил запрос. Возвращает `false`, если политика устройства запрещает приложению иметь такое разрешение и если ранее пользователь при запросе разрешения выбрал параметр "Не спрашивать снова"
- [requestPermissions()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int)) - метод запрашивает разрешение путем показа диалогового окна. Приложение не может настраивать или изменять это диалоговое окно. Если Пользователю требуется объяснить необходимость некоторого разрешения, то это нужно сделать до вызова этого метода.
- [onRequestPermissionsResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html#onRequestPermissionsResult(int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[])) - метод вызывается после показа диалогового окна и ответа Пользователя. Приложение должно переопределить этот метод, чтобы узнать, было ли предоставлено разрешение

[Источник](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)