# Android java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/myfile (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android

недавно начал изучать андроид и при написании приложения столкнулся с такой проблемой связанной с сериализацией, для создания файла использую следующий код:

```
        String filename = "myfile";
        String fileContents = "Hello world!";
        FileOutputStream outputStream;
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + filename);

        try {

            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            outputStream.write(fileContents.getBytes());
            outputStream.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

в androidmanifest поставил разрешение:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

в эмуляторе отрабатывает нормально, а вот если пытаюсь запустить приложение через телефон вылетает вот такая вот ошибка

```
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/myfile (Permission denied)
                  at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
                  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
                  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:169)
                  at com.yar.serialize.TestSer.<init>(TestSer.java:25)
                  at com.yar.SplitMainActivity.onCreate(SplitMainActivity.java:34)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6860)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2674)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2782)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1521)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6228)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

телефон redmi 4x

так же не помогает указать просто путь "/sdcard/сохраняемыый_файл.bin"

результат идентичен.

Comment: С 6 андроида опасные разрешения надо запрашивать в рантайме, просто указать его в манифесте - недостаточно

Comment: @Ярослав Ну что, получилось?

Comment: @Anton Sorokin вроде как да, спасибо за помощь

Comment: @Ярослав так прими ответ

Comment: @Anton Sorokin а как? я ж только зарегался и никогда не сидел до этого на подобных ресурсах,

Comment: @Ярослав рядом с моим ответом, между кнопками повысить/понизить репутацию  галочка стоит, нажми ее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перевод исключения:

*Permission denied* - **отказано в доступе**.

By [Flippy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194625/flippy):

> С 6 андроида опасные разрешения надо запрашивать в Runtime, просто указать его в манифесте - недостаточно.

(В любой версии Android разрешения из этих двух категорий все равно необходимо декларировать в Манифесте.)

By [Habr](https://habr.com/post/278945/):

> Разрешения делятся на два типа (есть и другие, но они нас не интересуют):
>
> обычные (normal);
>
> опасные (dangerous).
>
> Обычные разрешения будут получены приложением при установке, никакого
>   подтверждения от пользователя не потребуется (немного спорный момент,
>   на мой взгляд, стоило бы уведомлять пользователя об обязательных
>   разрешениях). В дальнейшем отозвать их у приложения будет невозможно.
>   Опасные же должны быть запрошены в процессе работы приложения и в
>   любой момент могут быть отозваны. Список опасных и не очень разрешений
>   можно посмотреть [тут](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous).

Из [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/766637/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-permissions-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81-23-api-%D0%B2-runtime/766638#766638) TimurVI:

> Если вашему приложению требуется "небезопасное" разрешение, вы должны
>   проверить, имеете ли вы это разрешение каждый раз, когда выполняете
>   операцию, требующую это разрешение.
>
> Некоторые методы:
>
> - [ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String)) - метод проверяет , имеете ли вы (приложение) разрешение. Возвращает
>     `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED` если есть, приложение может
>     перейти к требуемой операции. Возвращает
>     `PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED` если нет, приложение должно явно
>     запросить разрешение.
> - [shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String)) - метод позволяет определить необходимость объяснения Пользователю необходимости
>     запрашиваемого разрешения. Возвращает `true` если приложение
>     запрашивало это разрешение ранее, и пользователь отклонил запрос.
>     Возвращает `false`, если политика устройства запрещает приложению
>     иметь такое разрешение и если ранее пользователь при запросе
>     разрешения выбрал параметр "Не спрашивать снова"
> - [requestPermissions()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int)) - метод запрашивает разрешение путем показа диалогового окна. Приложение не может настраивать или изменять
>     это диалоговое окно. Если Пользователю требуется объяснить
>     необходимость некоторого разрешения, то это нужно сделать до вызова
>     этого метода.
> - [onRequestPermissionsResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html#onRequestPermissionsResult(int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[])) - метод вызывается после показа диалогового окна и ответа Пользователя. Приложение должно
>     переопределить этот метод, чтобы узнать, было ли предоставлено
>     разрешение

Пример реализации с сайта [JavaDevBlog](https://javadevblog.com/rabota-s-runtime-permissions-v-android-6-poluchaem-razresheniya-programmno.html):

1)Узнать, получено ли в приложении необходимое разрешение. Например, так:

```
private boolean isPermissionGranted(String permission) {
    // проверяем разрешение - есть ли оно у нашего приложения
    int permissionCheck = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
    // true - если есть, false - если нет
    return permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}
```

2)Если разрешения нет, то запросить его с помощью метода `requestPermissions()`:

```
private void requestPermission(String permission, int requestCode) {
    // запрашиваем разрешение
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, 
           new String[]{permission}, requestCode);
}
```

Сразу несколько разрешений можно запросить так:

```
 public void requestMultiplePermissions() {
   ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
           new String[] {
                   Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
                   Manifest.permission.READ_SMS
           },
           PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

3)Обработать результат запроса на получение разрешений можно так:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[],
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    // проверка по запрашиваемому коду
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // разрешение успешно получено
        } else {
            // разрешение не получено
        }
    } else {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

А вообще, советую почитать [первоисточник](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html), там про все написано.